# How long must I wait for a 15 sat/B transaction to be confirmed or dropped by the network? What else can be done?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations, spending

I know my question will likely be marked as [a duplicate](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it), but I do not see how to apply that answer in the case of a Ledger Nano S wallet. Doesn't using the Bitcoin wallet software require downloading 200 GB? I cannot do this. I also ask a few more questions related to this situation.

5 centiBitcoin was sent to Coinbase December 12th and is still marked on their site as 'Pending'. However, their link to live.blockcypher.com says, "No transaction found with the hash [string of numbers and letters]".

It was sent from a Segwit-enabled Ledger Nano S that had received those funds from Coinbase. Their Chrome Bitcoin wallet app lists the transaction as 'unconfirmed', and its link to blockchain.info does show information about the transaction, including a 'received time'.

The fee is 14.781 sat/B, i.e. 57.5 microBitcoin. How many days must I wait for this transaction to be processed? Or, how long must I wait for the transaction to be rejected from the record so that I may respend? Or are the funds locked away forever?

The commonly referenced answer says,

> expect it to be ignored for an unknown amount of time until a miner decides to process it and solves the block; this could be several days to several weeks, possibly never. Your wallet and any Bitcoin node will show it as unconfirmed, your transaction is stuck in limbo.

So then this 5 cBTC is now literally "buried in a mine" and may never be dug back out?

I contacted Coinbase but they merely said, "I’ll pass your message [of concern and support for BIP 148 / SegWit] along for consideration for the team." Are they implying my funds are frozen until they enable SegWit? Why wouldn't they have already enabled it?

Comment: Please provide the transaction id, would be easier to help.

Comment: @PieterWuille, the first paragraph explains how this question is not a duplicate of that one, although there is overlap.

Comment: @Chak, what is the transaction ID used for, and why is it helpful to know it? (I am concerned about attempts to double-spend the coins before I can access them, so I am trying to provide sufficient information while keeping it anonymous.)

Comment: Is impossible to double-spend without the private key. [A transaction ID](https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/211160663-How-can-I-look-up-a-transaction-on-the-blockchain-) is like a publicly available id number for a bitcoin transaction. Example: [This transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/c6a0682657598ffae89fbad0e4b9978ef050f2f80f4053570c12d5dcdb61170b)  where the random characters after /tx/ is the transaction id.